# Where can I safely store records (i.e. files) that a standard (limited) user cannot modify or delete?

Tags: .net, windows-services, filesystems, user-accounts, localsystem

I have a service auditing standard users of the local PC. I would like to get the performance logs uploaded to an SQL server but as a first step, and for simplicity I need to store them, as well as the config.ini which initializes the service in a special folder accessible only to the localsystem account.

Is there such a folder and where would I find it?

Comment: @sll data would be stored for benefit of localsystem account only, and later cascaded down to users if needed. As an aside I found that for Vista and newer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Tasks_that_trigger_a_UAC_prompt, not perfect as only a UAC prompt away from deleting program files, but better than what I've got in XP.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) feature

> With isolated storage, data is always isolated by user and by
>   assembly. Credentials such as the origin or the strong name of the
>   assembly determine assembly identity. Data can also be isolated by
>   application domain, using similar credentials

How-tos:

- [Create Files and Directories in Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h2ws3ft%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Read and Write to Files in Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Unless the auditing service is running under different credentials the user has still access to files in isolated storage. They're a little hard to find but that's just security through obscurity.

Comment: @riezebosch : I supposing that data would be stored under the "service's account" isolated storage not under the each specific user which has been monitored, but I believe this point still not clear

Comment: For XP "<SYSTEMDRIVE>\Documents and Settings\<user>\" is root of isolated storage. There is no <user> entry there for localSystem. I see the isolated storage is not intended for generated log data, which spurs me on to learn SQL Server, but how could I authenticate automatically and securely if that or (for Vista+) <SYSTEMDRIVE>\Users\<user>\ is visible to the user? I may be a while verifying sample code (without fast user switching)...

Comment: @John Silver : Could youn try to create any file in isolated storage from Service?

Comment: @sll Sure, I followed your link and got the example working from my *admin* account, then I logged in as an XP "Limited" User and I leafed through the path above to find the files and directories just created. I even opened one but found it to be empty. Now I need to try it from the localsystem account. There must be a better way, I can't imagine it working because <user> doesn't exist when the service starts up (and reads its config).

Comment: I thinks my problems are (1) FAT32, (2) XP Home. Sorry for being such a dolt!